# Selenium PHP: Unable to Download a xls file in Chrome headless mode

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, download, xls, headless

I am trying to download an xls file using a link in Headless mode.
The file is getting downloaded in head mode.
Scenario:

- Need to click on a link

  - There is no link that can get retrieved as href attribute is not present
- After clicking on the link, a new tab gets opened.
- Once the tab gets opened download starts.
- I am unable to switch to a tab in headless mode as it gets immediately closed.

Chrome options set:

```
$chromeoptions = ["--headless", 
            "--disable-gpu", 
            "--window-size=1920,1200",
            "--ignore-certificate-errors",
            "--disable-extensions",
            "--no-sandbox",
            "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
            "--disable-popup-blocking"];
```

```
$preferences = array(
                "download.prompt_for_download" => false, 
                'download.default_directory' => $this->downloadDirectoryPath, 
                "directory_upgrade" => true,
                "credentials_enable_service" => false,
                "Browser.setDownloadBehaviour" => array(
                    "behavior" => "allow", 
                    "downloadPath" => $this->downloadDirectoryPath
                ),
                "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" => "application/vnd.ms-excel"
            );
```

Selenium Version: 4.8.1
Chrome Driver version: 81.0.4044.138

Note: I can't upgrade to the latest Chrome version as we purposefully installed this version.

Tried setting Chrome options but nothing worked.
Does anybody face the same problem with Selenium Chrome?